# Visual Studio XNA 4.0 Refresh - Problems creating new projects and opening existing ones

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to create a new XNA 4.0 Refresh C# Project in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I previously had XNA 4.0 installed, but a course I am in requires 4.0 Refresh. Whenever I attempt to create the project in VS2010, I get the following error message:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.

I have researched this problem for a while, and here are the suggestions that I have tried with no success

- Launching VS2010 with the /setup flag
- Resetting the import/export settings
- Completely uninstalling VS2010 and XNA 4.0 Refresh (twice), the second time using the uninstall utility from MSDN

On a possibly related note, if I try to open an XNA project created on a different system, I get the following error:

> 'C:\Users\...\Game.contentproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.contentproj) is not supported by this version of the application.

Here is a gist of the log output:
https://gist.github.com/2341704

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

XNA is no more supported in Windows 8 development. I highly recommended that you should change to [Monogame](http://monogame.net). It is open source port of XNA. And it will work with new Visual Studio too.

As far as your specific issue is concern. In old project, Content management was part of XNA project. But later on they change that part and move Content out side of Project. Just to make content sharing between different projects. Specifically when you are developing for Zune, Windows Phone and XBOX. And that is giving issue for opening project.

Easiest way to upgrade is, create new project and move all your code. As far as I know there is no or very little change at Code part. And change is also at very high level which normally not widely used in games by developers. And you content will be in new content project that will be included in project. And if you create new game, it will come like that only.

You can also shift to Monogame as mentioned above. You code will still stays the same. And for few project like windows game with OpenGL option, you don't even need to move the content to another project.

Please let me know if any further details required.

PS: As per last update XNA is officially not getting ahead by Microsoft, Support of new XBOX is yet to declared. But using Monogame you can target multiple platform with your XNA knowledge.